# Do military titles get capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, writing-style, proper-nouns

I'm pretty sure "Commander Shepard" is preferable to "commander Shepard," but I'm less sure about "the Commander" vs "the commander."  On one hand, I'm pretty sure "commander" is a common noun in this usage, and I certainly wouldn't write "a Commander."  But on the other, capitalizing it in this instance feels righter to my native ear.  I'm starting to think this is like the serial comma (i.e. pick a style and be consistent), but if there is a real rule, I'd like to follow it.

Comment: When applied to a person, capitalize it. When referring to the position, don't.  "While Captain Kirk is famous, most merchant ship captains toil in obscurity"

Comment: @Oldcat: What about this?  "The Captain ordered the *Enterprise* to warp."  "Captain" refers to a specific person here, but does it still get capitalized?

Comment: I'd consider that an abridgement of Cap Kirk, so I'd capitalize it.

Comment: First off, *Commander* is not the same as *commander.* Check the context. What's Shepard? Does he work as the commander of something or does he hold the designation/ title of 'Commander?'

Comment: @Oldcat Source?

Comment: @Kris: Shepard holds the military rank of commander.  Semi-independently, Shepard is *also* in command of a ship.

Comment: "Shepard holds the military rank of **Commander.** " http://masseffect.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Why_do_the_geth_call_you_%22Shepard-Commander%22

Comment: BTW Regarding *righter,* see http://codifiers.weblog.leidenuniv.nl/2009/03/30/righter-or-more-right/ and http://www.nytimes.com/1997/03/16/magazine/through-the-wronger.html

Comment: @Kris: I like "righter," even if it is probably wronger than "more right."  Never in formal writing, of course.  I'd put it in the same category as "thrice."

Comment: What could be an issue with *thrice* https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=define+%22thrice%22 and how is that like *righter* ? Just curious.

Comment: @Kris: "Thrice" is [far less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thrice%2Cthree+times&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000) than "three times."  And "righter" just sounds fanciful to me.

Comment: I just capitalized "General" when from context it wasn't clear that it was the military title and not the adjective.  "He was a general" just a looked wrong, as if I had written an incomplete sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a style issue, and the appropriate style for you to use depends on which style guide you or your publisher or school generally follows and whether that guide specifies a rule for handling military (or other hierarchical) titles. The influential (in the United States) *Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003), lays out one approach:

> **Titles and Offices**
>
> **8.21** *Capitalization*: the general rule/ Civil, military, religious and professional titles are capitalized when they immediately precede a personal name and are thus used as part of the name (usually replacing the title holder's first name. Titles are normally lowercased when following a name or used in place of a name ...
>
> [Examples:] President Lincoln; the president; General Bradley; the general; Cardinal Newman; the cardinal Dean Mueller; the dean; Governors Edgar and Ryan; the governors

Exceptions exist, according to *Chicago*, but these primarily involve instances of direct address (Yes sir, Captain!") or formal introduction ("Ladies and Gentlemen, the Prime Minister"), as well as various special forms of displayed lists or promotional presentations.

In a normal situation in which you were referring to a particular commander as "the commander" (or "the Commander"), *Chicago* advises using "the commander."

The *Oxford Guide to Style* (2003) agrees with *Chicago* on capitalization of titles used immediately before a name and noncapitalization of titles identified immediately after a name:

> **4.1.7 Titles of rank or relationship, and nicknames:**
>
> ...
>
> Titles used as identification or clarification after a name normally are not capitalized (especially in US usage):
>
> [Examples:] Miss Dunn, the head teacher; Anne Williams, our mnaging director; Mr. Gladstone, the prime minister; Dr Primrose, the parish vicar
>
> Titles used before a name are normally capitalized, and are not followed by a comma:
>
> [Examples:] Head Teacher Miss Dunn; Managing Director Anne Williams; the Prime Minister Mr. Gladstone; The Reverend Dr Primrose

But *Oxford* breaks with *Chicago* on the very point that the OP asks about:

> Capitals are preferred, however, when a short-form mention of a title is used as synonym for a particular person, an organization in an institutional or official sense, or a government:
>
> [Relevant examples:] the Duke; the Princess, the Ministry (of Defence); the Centre's policy

So if you already introduced Commander Shepard earlier in a piece of writing, and you now wish to refer to the same person as "the Commander," *Oxford* advises you to capitalize the *C* in *Commander*.

In the United States, I believe, the *Chicago* style is more prevalent than the *Oxford* style. It is certainly the style we followed at the tech magazines where I've worked. But in the UK, the Oxford style may be dominant.

Comment: I'm afraid we have not covered to present case here, though.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Canadian Press style guide.  In certain circumstances a military rank may be used in first reference before the name of an officer who has retired.  Do not use the abbreviation Ret. but put retired before the lowercase rank.  retired captain John Smith.

Answer (score -3):

All titles are capitalized. Verbs aren't.

When using *captain* in sentences, capitalize it when referring to an individual, even if not by name. As @Oldcat suggested, you would capitalize in a sentence starting with "The Captain..." because you're referring to one person, who has the title of Captain. But when you're using the word to refer to captains non-personally, as a verb, i.e. "Sometimes captains are..." or "All ships are captained..." I wouldn't capitalize it.

Comment: When you speak of the captain, you are referring to just one person, but you are placing them in a category. An initial capital is just as incorrect as it would be in 'my **f**ather'.