# Use of title capitals

Tags: word-usage

Admiral Gonzeles told his men to search for a gun. A soldier asked if the admiral had any further instructions.

Should the second time admiral is used be capitalized or not?

Thanks

Frank

Comment: Similar question - aready answered under 'Capitalization": http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209631/do-military-titles-get-capitalized

Answer (score 1):

It should not be capitalized.

Capitalize titles when they are used before names, unless the title is followed by a comma. Do not capitalize the title if it is used after a name or instead of a name.

Consider the two examples:

> 1) Admiral Gonzeles told his men to search for a gun.
>
> 2) A soldier asked if Admiral Gonzeles had any further instructions.

Both of them are correct. In example 2, "Admiral" is capitalized because it is used before a name. But, if you combine those two sentences like you did, you should not capitalize the word "admiral" because it is used instead of the name.

***Corroborating sources:***

GrammarBook.com: [Capitalization Rules, Rule 4](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp)

Capital Community College Foundation: [Capitalizing People's Titles 
and the Names of Political Entities](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/capitals.htm)

Comment: This is generally very sound advice, and I would happily upvote your answer if you linked to a reference work (or even better, two reference works) that reach the same conclusion and use essentially the same reasoning that you do. For the most part, EL&U strongly prefers answers that include support from authoritative sources. Thanks!

Comment: My answer comes straight from a very good English learning source.I will be happy to provide the source. :)

Comment: I have provided the source.

Comment: +1. Nice job of supporting your answer. The first URL didn't work because the final letter in it (p) had been inadvertently lopped off, so I added that, and (for readers' benefit) I identified the source links in English words rather than with just the raw URLs. But I think that this is now a very solid answer to the original poster's question.